# requestAnimationFrame and eventListener

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, requestanimationframe

I'm trying to make an illustrated book (basic). It was working fine until I added an animated scene. I added the animated scene using requestAnimationFrame. Although it animates, it doesn't switch between scene four(the animated scene) and scene one(the first scene).When I comment the requestAnimationFrame in the function of sceneFour(), it switches between scene four and scene one. But it doesn't animate.
I was wondering what is it that I'm doing wrong here. Thanks! 
This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Functions in Khan Academy</title>
    <style>
        #c{
            border: 2px black solid;
        }
        canvas {
            display: block; 
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id ="c" width="750" height="750"></canvas>
<script>
    var c = document.querySelector("#c");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var currentScene = 1;
    var radius = 40;
    var xPos = 600;
    var yPos = 340;


    var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || 
                                    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || 
                                    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
                                    window.msRequestAnimationFrame; 
        //Scene One
        function sceneOne(){
            currentScene = 1;
            ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(235,247,255)";
            ctx.fillRect(0,0,750,750);
            ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 85, 255)";
            ctx.font = "70px Impact";
            ctx.fillText("The Story of Winston", 40, 130); 


            var img = new Image();
            img.onload = function(){
            ctx.drawImage(img, 280, 270, 150, 150);  
        };
             img.src = "running.JPG";

        };

       //Scene Two
       function sceneTwo() {
            currentScene = 2;
            ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(173,239,255)";
            ctx.fillRect(0,0,750,750);
            ctx.fillStyle="rgb(7, 14, 145)";
            ctx.fillText("Lil Winston is born!", 10, 100);
        };

        //Scee Three
        function sceneThree() {
            currentScene = 3;
            ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(173,239,255)";
            ctx.fillRect(0,0,750,750);
            ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(7, 14, 145)";
            ctx.fillText("Winston grows up!", 10, 100);
        }; 

        //animated scene four

        function sceneFour(){
            currentScene = 4;
            //background
            ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(194,255,222)";
            ctx.fillRect(0,0,750,750);

            //face
            ctx.fillStyle ="rgb(255, 255, 0)";
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(xPos, yPos, radius, 0, 2*Math.PI);
            ctx.fill();

            //left eye
            ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 0, 0)";
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(xPos-20, yPos-20, radius-35, 0, 2*Math.PI);
            ctx.fill();

            //right eye
            ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 0, 0)";
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(xPos+20, yPos-20, radius - 35, 0, 2*Math.PI);
            ctx.fill();

            //mouth
            ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255, 0, 0)";
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(xPos, yPos+10, radius-25, 0, 2*Math.PI);
            ctx.fill();

            //stick
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(xPos, yPos+40);
            ctx.lineTo(xPos, yPos+150);
            ctx.stroke();

            //left hand
            ctx.moveTo(xPos, yPos+40);
            ctx.lineTo(xPos-40, yPos+80);
            ctx.stroke();

            //right hand
            ctx.moveTo(xPos, yPos+40);
            ctx.lineTo(xPos+40, yPos+80);
            ctx.stroke();

            //left leg
            ctx.moveTo(xPos, yPos+150);
            ctx.lineTo(xPos-50, yPos+180);
            ctx.stroke();

            //right leg
            ctx.moveTo(xPos, yPos+150);
            ctx.lineTo(xPos+50, yPos+180);
            ctx.stroke();


            yPos = yPos -0.5;

            if(yPos === 306){
                yPos =340;
            };

            //requestAnimationFrame(sceneFour);     
        };

        c.addEventListener("click", function(){
        switch(currentScene) {
        case 1:
            sceneTwo();
            break;
        case 2:
            sceneThree();
            break;
        case 3:
            sceneFour();
            break;
        case 4:
        sceneOne();
        break;
    }
});     
        sceneOne();


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need to somehow let `sceneFour` function know it's no longer required to run the animation - unfortunately, you set `currentScene` inside that function, so you can't use that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, remove the `currentScene = n` from all of scene* functions

change sceneFour as follows

```
function sceneFour() {
    //... removed for brevity
    if (currentScene == 4) {
        requestAnimationFrame(sceneFour);
    } else {
        sceneOne();
    }
}
```

Have to do it that way otherwise you can end up with one last frame of sceneFour clobbering static scene 1

change the click handler as follows

```
c.addEventListener("click", function(){
    currentScene = currentScene % 4 + 1;
    switch(currentScene) {
    case 1:
        //sceneOne();
        break;
    case 2:
        sceneTwo();
        break;
    case 3:
        sceneThree();
        break;
    case 4:
        sceneFour();
        break;
    }
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work. The animation on the fourth scene doesn't work.

Comment: the changed code should now work @abidishajia (I've checked it this time)

Comment: Actually, can you please explain what this line of code does?
currentScene = currentScene % 4 + 1;

Comment: it's a way of saying `currentScene = currentScene  + 1; if (currentScene >4) currentScene = 1;`